# PHP - как добавить к массиву новый элемент из другого массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_id] => 3449 [name] => Тр2 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product_id] => 3450 [name] => Труб ) 
[2] => Array ( [product_id] => 3464 [name] => Сетк ) 
[3] => Array ( [product_id] => 3466 [name] => MTd ) 
)
```

И

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 8 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 9 )  
)
```

Как в первый массив добавить новый элемент, например 'id' к каждому элементу, который будет содержать значения из второго массива? Во втором массиве содержаться элементы с ключем 'id', которые должны быть назначены первому массиву попорядку.

Должен получиться вот такой массив:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_id] => 3449 [name] => Тр2  [id] => 7) 
[1] => Array ( [product_id] => 3450 [name] => Труб [id] => 7) 
[2] => Array ( [product_id] => 3464 [name] => Сетк [id] => 8) 
[3] => Array ( [product_id] => 3466 [name] => MTd [id] => 9) 
)
```

Comment: Код массивов лучше постить как в коде (хотя бы var_export), чтобы отвечающим проще было использовать его в своих ответах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно мутировать оригинальный массив, то можно вот так:

```
$arr = [
    ['a' => 1,],
    ['a' => 2,],
    ['a' => 3,],
];
$ids = [
    ['id' => 11],
    ['id' => 12],
    ['id' => 13],
];

array_walk($arr, function(&$el, $i) use ($ids) {$el = array_merge($el, $ids[$i]);});

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Круто. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Компактный вариант *(и без ссылок)*

```
$arr = [
    ['a' => 1,],
    ['a' => 2,],
    ['a' => 3,],
];
$ids = [
    ['id' => 11],
    ['id' => 12],
    ['id' => 13],
];

$arr = array_map('array_merge', $arr, $ids);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Без ссылок-то оно без ссылок. Но не in-place)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sr=array(array('product_id'=>'3449','name'=>'Тр2'),
    array('product_id'=>'3450','name' => 'Труб'), 
array('product_id'=>'3464','name'=>'Сетк'), 
array('product_id' => '3466','name'=>'MTd'));
$tu=array(array('id' => '7'), 
array('id' => '7'), 
array('id' => '8'), 
array('id' => '9')  
); 


for($i = 0; $i<count($sr); $i++){

array_push($sr[$i], $tu[$i]['id']);
}
print_r($sr);
```